# C# lazy load approach with dynamic generic types (Func + Action)

Tags: c#, generics

I have a system that acts like a "Message Bus"

```
    interface IMessageHandler<T> {
        void Handle(T message);
    }

    class MessageBus {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> _handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();

        void AddHandler<T>(IMessageHandler<T> handler) {
            _messageHandlers[typeof(T)] = message => messageHandler.Handle((T)message);
        }

        public void Handle(object message)
        {
            _handlers[message.GetType()](message);
        }

    }
```

But instead of passing directly the instance of the message handler, I want to pass it a Func, to do a lazy load approach (only instance the message handler when it's requested for the first time. Then if I have 1000 message handlers, and in an execution I only use 5, I can avoid instantiating the other 995)

My current approach to accomplish it (omitting all the part of having a list with the definitions + instances and checking that the instance is already resolved, etc),

Is in the `Handle` invoke it with:

```
var messageType = message.GetType();
var definition = _definitions[messageType];
var instance = definition();
var handleMethod = instance.GetType().GetMethod("Handle");
handleMethod.Invoke(new [] {message});
```

But the performance will be bad, is there any other better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<Type, Lazy<Action<object>>>` instead of `Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>`, so instance of an handler will be created only once and only when it is necessary.

```
    class MessageBus
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, Lazy<Action<object>>> _handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Lazy<Action<object>>>();

        public void AddHandler<T>(Func<IMessageHandler<T>> handlerFactory)
        {
            Func<Action<object>> objectHandlerFactory = CreateObjectHandlerFactory(handlerFactory);
            _handlers[typeof(T)] = new Lazy<Action<object>>(objectHandlerFactory);
        }

        public void Handle(object message)
        {
            _handlers[message.GetType()].Value(message);
        }

        private Func<Action<object>> CreateObjectHandlerFactory<T>(Func<IMessageHandler<T>> handlerFactory)
        {
            return () =>
            {
                var handler = handlerFactory();
                return message => handler.Handle((T)message);
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: it works, thanks. Is it the usage of "Lazy" performant? or is it better to use two dictionaries in the class (one for the definitions & another for the instances) and check on every call if the instance exists?